# Openapi feign client generation body/query param mismatch

Tags: java, http, swagger, spring-cloud-feign, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have a swagger spec

```
/authentication-service/authorize:
  post:
    tags:
      - Auth
    summary: Authorize
    requestBody:
      content:
        application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
          schema:
            properties:
              redirect_uri:
                type: string
                example: http://localhost
              client_id:
                type: string
                example: asdf
          encoding:
            redirect_uri:
              allowReserved: true
            client_id:
              allowReserved: true
    parameters:
      - name: Content-Type
        in: header
        schema:
          type: string
        example: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    responses:
      '200':
        description: Successful response
        content:
          application/json: {}
```

as you can see it is a `post` with content type of `x-www-form-urlencoded` with a `requestBody`.

This is what `org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:6.0.1` generates out of that:

```
    @Operation(
        operationId = "authenticationServiceAuthorizeGet",
        summary = "API-AS02 Authorize",
        tags = { "Auth" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Successful response")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/authentication-service/authorize",
        produces = "application/json",
        consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    )
    ResponseEntity<Void> authenticationServiceAuthorizePost(
        @Parameter(name = "Content-Type", description = "") @RequestHeader(value = "Content-Type", required = false) String contentType,
        @Parameter(name = "redirect_uri", description = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "redirect_uri", required = false) String redirectUri,
        @Parameter(name = "client_id", description = "") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "client_id", required = false) String clientId,
 
...more params generated...
    );
```

Now when I finally try to use this feign client, it compiles following request for me:

```
[POST] to [https://api-us-dev<obfuscatedURL>/authentication-service/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost&client_id=oidc_pkce....
```

So as you can see the compiled feign client calls POST request with *encoded* query params that were delcared as `requestBody` in the spec above.

This request is being rejected from the server. The server is avaiting those params to be encoded in the *body* of the request.

However that's how openapi generator & feign client does it for me.

2 questions on that:

- Is it generated correctly?
- Regardless of it being correct or not, I
  need to send payload in the body as per server impl. Can you point
  out to me how to change swagged spec for it to be encoded as body k=v
  pairs?

[How to POST form-url-encoded data with Spring Cloud Feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803093/how-to-post-form-url-encoded-data-with-spring-cloud-feign)

does not do it for me, the parameters are still encoded in the query instead of body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to POST form-url-encoded data with Spring Cloud Feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803093/how-to-post-form-url-encoded-data-with-spring-cloud-feign)

Comment: will try that out, i suppose you're pointing out the formDataEncoder to me..

Comment: i think that encoder is a good point, but I need to make it generate `@requestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` because with @RequestParam it keeps sending it as query params even with that encoder

Comment: how do you call it? https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form/blob/master/feign-form/src/main/java/feign/form/FormEncoder.java#L89 expects that `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: it is set. i can tell because i have an interceptor and i see it in the headers. also generated code has `consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in it

Comment: just have checked and that call in not hitting the encoder you pointed out. that might be a problem too... i think problem is in my swagger markup, maybe it's not explicit enough for openapi to generate it the right way, idk