# OpenFeign not decoding response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

```java
@FeignClient(name = "Authorization-API", url = "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1")
public interface AuthorizationApi {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/access_token")
    Token getToken(@PathVariable("grant_type") String grantType,
                      @PathVariable String code,
                      @PathVariable("redirect_uri") String redirectUrl,
                      @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String authorizationHeader,
                      @RequestHeader("User-agent") String agent
    );
}
```

Call:

```java
        Token token = authorizationApi.getToken(
                "authorization_code",
                code,
                REDIRECT_URI,
                getAuthorizationCredentials(),
                "porymol");
        System.out.println(token.access_token()); //returns null
```

Token record:

```java
public record Token(String access_token, String token_type, Long expires_in, String scope, String refresh_token) {
}
```

When I make request from Postman I get this response:

```json
{
    "access_token": "token",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "refresh_token": "token",
    "scope": "read"
}
```

Trying to get any value from Token returns null

Java 17, Spring boot 3

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Tried naming field `accessToken` instead of `access_token`?

Comment: @ILyaCyclone yes, same thing

Comment: You can set logging level to FULL https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#feign-logging and check actual response from remote API.

Comment: @ILyaCyclone that helped thanks. I had to set content type to APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have declared two path variables which dont show up the path:
`@PathVariable String code` and `@PathVariable("redirect_uri") String redirectUrl`.

Overall it looks like you are trying to request an oauth access token which requires an request of content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Maybee this helps: [How to POST form-url-encoded data with Spring Cloud Feign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803093/how-to-post-form-url-encoded-data-with-spring-cloud-feign)

Comment: Setting content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded did the job. Thanks