# Spring open feign not sending body (empty body) when content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-cloud-feign

This is my feign endpoint

```
@PostMapping(value = "url", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
MpcsAuthResponse obtainAccessToken(@RequestBody MpcsTokenRequest request);
```

and when I enable feign full logs I see that the body is empty

```
c.k.c.t.m.m.client.mpcs.MpcsClient -- [MpcsClient#obtainAccessToken] ---> POST <url> HTTP/1.1
11:16:47.532 [main] DEBUG c.k.c.t.m.m.client.mpcs.MpcsClient -- [MpcsClient#obtainAccessToken] Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
11:16:47.532 [main] DEBUG c.k.c.t.m.m.client.mpcs.MpcsClient -- [MpcsClient#obtainAccessToken] 
11:16:47.532 [main] DEBUG c.k.c.t.m.m.client.mpcs.MpcsClient -- [MpcsClient#obtainAccessToken] 
11:16:47.532 [main] DEBUG c.k.c.t.m.m.client.mpcs.MpcsClient -- [MpcsClient#obtainAccessToken] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

I have other feign clients that are working fine. The only time this happens is when I use APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE.

I am on Java 17, spring boot 3.1.0 and fiegn comes from

```
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.0.3
```

NOTE: If I use just String instead of the MpcsTokenRequest dto it works, so it is probably something with the encoders, but I can't figure it out

EDIT: this is how my DTO looks like

```
public record MpcsTokenRequest(@FormProperty("client_id")
                               String clientId,
                               @FormProperty("client_secret")
                               String clientSecret,
                               @FormProperty("grant_type")
                               String grantType) {
}
```

My client configuration

```
public class MpcsClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Encoder formEncoder() {
        return new feign.form.FormEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }
}
```

The problem was that feign doesn't serialize the form if its a record.
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign-form/issues/105

Converting my DTO to POJO solved it.

Comment: Did you check this answer yet? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54841998/7506820

Comment: Yes it didn't works and I assumed that the data there is a bit outdated

Answer (score 0):

you can try `@SpringQueryMap`:

```
@PostMapping(value = "url", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
MpcsAuthResponse obtainAccessToken(@SpringQueryMap MpcsTokenRequest request);
```

but make sure to add `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE`  at the resource you want to consume : `@PostMapping(value = "/url",consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)`